# How to speed up select statement which has a count command

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count

I am using Mysql5.x, have a db table for users with an integer field named `fld_experience`. As the name suggests it holds experiences of the users and I want to get the order (rank) of the user in the whole list thus I will be able to show the user's rank in the whole table. Since other users' experience may change any time, I cannot store the rank as a field, have to calculate on demand.

here is the sql statement I get the order of the user

```
SELECT COUNT( fld_experience ) + 1 
FROM tbl_users 
WHERE fld_experience > ( SELECT fld_experience 
                         FROM tbl_users 
                          WHERE fld_user_id = ?)
```

I want to speed up this request, how can I do it? 
I really wonder if indexing `fld_experience` would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT( fld_experience ) + 1 
FROM tbl_users, ( SELECT fld_experience 
                         FROM tbl_users 
                          WHERE fld_user_id = ?) selected_user
WHERE fld_experience > selected_user.fld_experience
```

Comment: why would it be faster?

Comment: it will be executed just once rather than for each line in WHERE

Comment: what about indexing, you think it would also be faster with and index on fld_experience?

Comment: Add index for the fld_experience column. But I would check current query. Run and see how fast is it and decide whether you need it faster.

Comment: here is the error message ...Error Code: 1052. Column 'fld_experience' in field list is ambiguous